# Array assignment to string

Tags: c#, php, c#-4.0

I have php code that puts some values into an Array as follows:

```
$hunter=addslashes($MessageArray[1]);
$time=addslashes($MessageArray[2]);
```

I wrote the same code in C# and wanted to know if it was correct.

```
string Hunter = Messagearray[1].tostring();
string time = Messagearray[2].tostring();
```

Comment: What's in the array?  Also, minor correction, it's `ToString()` -- Pascal cased.

Comment: What happened when you tested it? That should've been your fastest indicator.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare  this array contains Strings & Ints

Comment: @Josh Still i'm in middle of the code,still not tested it

Comment: When you say "Strings & Ints" are you saying the first item is a `string`, and the second is an `int`?

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe - Test it then return when you have an actual question.

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe: Are you using a C# IDE or are you compiling your code manually?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm writing code for sms gateway,no way to tested until finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As James mentioned, use Pascal casing:

```
string hunter = messageArray[1].ToString();
string time = messageArray[2].ToString();
```

Also, C# arrays are indexed starting at 0. You can change the starting index of arrays in PHP, but you can't in C#. Perhaps you *do* wish to take the 2nd and 3rd items, but keep it in mind. You might want:

```
string hunter = messageArray[0].ToString();
string time = messageArray[1].ToString();
```

As far as `addslashes()` goes, it will depend on your usage of `hunter` and `time`. If you're using them in a SQL statement, there are other ways of accomplishing the functionality of PHP's `addslashes()`.

Comment: He should be careful of trying to index specfic characters within a string unless he knows how long the string is otherwise he will cause an exception to happen.

Comment: @Ramhound: Very true, assuming `messageArray` is a string. The question doesn't make it clear -- I get the feeling `messageArray` is either a `string[]` or `object[]`. But you're right, whichever it is, the OP should stay within the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Snipped from [Here](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-AddSlashes-StripSlashes-Escape-String.html)

```
public static string AddSlashes(string input)
{
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"(\\)([\000\010\011\012\015\032\042\047\134\140])", "$2");
}
```

Usage:

```
//
        var Messagearray = new object[] { "item 0", 1 };
        var hunter = AddSlashes(Messagearray[0].ToString());
        var time = AddSlashes(Messagearray[1].ToString());
```

Comment: -1: That is not an equivalent implementation of PHP's [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

Comment: i think thisone not working with C# know ? addslashes is in php ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what addslashes do in PHP. I think perhaps adding slashes before and after the string. It's just a matter of configure the string.Format method.

Comment: @JohnPolvora: `addslashes()` escapes the single quote, double quote, backslash, and NULL character if present. It doesn't wrap the entire string in forward slashes.

Comment: ok I will check and edit now.

Comment: done, I've checked and edited.